# How to use @BasicMap for a HashMap whose key values are entities

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

How should I use EclipseLink's @BasicMap annotation for a map whose key value is an entity and the value is an Integer?

```
@Entity
class A {

   // This doesn't work, as the key is an entity
   @BasicMap
   private Map<B, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<B, Integer>();

}

@Entity
class B {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is not possible, as BasicMap only works for primary datatypes.

Comment: May I ask about the solution you ended up using? Did you use a different mapping or a different data structure, enclosing the data in the Map in an entity of its own? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but the thread is so old that I have no recollection of what I ended up doing. Probably a different data structure?